# SML consing a datatype list

Tags: list, sml, abstract-data-type

If I have this SML datatype

```
datatype json =
         Num of real
       | String of string
       | False
       | True
       | Null
       | Array of json list
       | Object of (string * json) list
```

Let's say I have this `Array` with only one `Object` which makes it a `json` list

```
Array[Object[("a", Num (1.0)),("b", True)]]
```

how can I cons a new `Object` onto this existing `Array`? I've tried a simple `::` to no avail

```
Object[("a", Num (1.0)),("b", True)]::Array[Object[("a", Num (2.0)),("b", True)]]
```

which gives an error. Do I have to build my own cons for this? It seems the SML list is `'a list` which should allow `json list` and work with `::`

Yes, this is a homework assignment from a past semester of *Programming Languages* at the U. of Washington that I'm doing on my own. [This](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/19sp/hw2.pdf) is the assignment.

My basic problem is I don't know how to add to an `Array` with recursion calls. If I need to generate an `Array` containing `Objects` and add a new `Object` to that starting `Array` with each recursion call, how would that be done? I've seen examples of `Succ` or `Cons`, e.g., a successor constructor, but those just create a recursive, nested object such as

```
val four = Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))
```

...but this isn't helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array [...]` is no a `json list`, it's a `json`, and `::` can't cons two `json`s into a list.

You need to cons onto the list "inside" the `Array`:

```
Array (Object [("a", Num 1.0)] :: ([Object [("a", Num 2.0)]]))
```

You probably want to add a "cons for JSON" function; something like

```
fun json_cons o (Array os) = Array (o :: os)
  | json_cons _ _ = ... handle structural error ...
```

You can also invent your own binary infix operator, but that's probably a bit on the advanced side for this assignment.

Comment: Thanks, this got me going again. However, the fact that `([Object [("a", Num 2.0)]])` is a `json list` like `[2]` is `'a list` is rather bizarre looking, and I would have been in many "guess-test" cycles.

Comment: `[2]` is an `int list`, not an `'a list` (you can't create an `'a list`, since they can't exist); `2` is an `int`, and adding the `[]` around it makes an  `int list`. If an expression `e` has the type `json`, `[e]` has the type  `json list`.

Comment: Good, but why are the parentheses necessary around `[Object [("a", Num 2.0)]]` for list consing? If `[2]` is an `int list`, why isn't just `[Object [("a", Num 2.0)]]` a `json list` ready for consing? Instead, I need `([Object [("a", Num 2.0)]])` to do consing.

Comment: Ok, you got me there... The parentheses are actually not necessary, due to the low precedence of `::`. I put them there for clarity, but `Array (Object [("a", Num 1.0)] :: [Object [("a", Num 2.0)]])` also works.

Answer (score 0):

With molbdnilo's help, I got past the mental block of how to create an `Array` list. Since `Array` is also a constructor, i.e., like a function, we can do things inside this constructor function call, namely, we can do a normal list cons *inside* the `Array` constructor

```
fun json_cons (ob, (Array os)) = Array (ob::os)
  | json_cons (_,_) = (Array [])
```

Testing

```
- json_cons (Object[("a", Num (1.0)),("b", True)], Array[])
val it = Array [Object [(#,#),(#,#)]] : json
```

Here's an another example at directly constructing

```
- Array (Object [("a", Num 1.0)] :: ([Object [("a", Num 2.0)]]))
val it = Array [Object [(#,#)],Object [(#,#)]] : json
```

For someone used to `1::[2]` this is bizarre, especially the `([Object[...]])` as the cdr part. So here is the code

```
fun make_silly_json (i) =
    case i of
        0 => Array [Object []]
      | x => json_cons (Object [("n", Num (Real.fromInt (x))),("b", True)], make_silly_json (x-1))
```

Testing

```
make_silly_json 3
    val it = Array [Object [(#,#),(#,#)],Object [(#,#),(#,#)],Object [(#,#),(#,#)],Object []] : json
```

...types...

Answer (score 0):

Thank for molbdnilo's help on creating the "cons for JSON" function. Attaching a tail recursion version of the solution:

```
fun make_silly_json i =
    let fun aux(i, acc) =
        if i = 0
        then acc
        else let val json_val = Object[("n", Num(int_to_real(i))),("b", True)]
                 fun json_con (obj, (Array os)) =
                    Array(obj::os)
                  | json_con (_,_) = (Array [])
             in
                aux(i-1, json_con(json_val, acc))
             end
    in aux(i, Array[])
    end
```